# Как получить доступ к объекту созданному в другом потоке?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, c++

Пишу на managed C++, VS express 2008, проект Windows Forms.

Столкнулся с проблемой - во время вычислений интерфейс программы зависает намертво, чего и следовало ожидать, ведь все висит на одном потоке.

Я создаю дочерний поток для вычислений, но мне нужно в то же время иметь доступ к форме, для повышения значения ProgressBar'a, нажимания кнопок.

Вот здесь я застрял... Пробовал с делегатами, не разобрался, потому-что в интернете мало примеров реализованных на C++, большинство на C#, а C++ капризный и никак не могу адаптировать код к нему...

Помогите примером и объяснениями пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

```
if (control -> InvokeRequired)
  control -> Invoke(new Action __gc*(DoSomething));
else
  DoSomething();
```